# vector<vector<float>>::size_type or vector<float>::size_type when dealing with vector<vector<float>>'s size()?

Tags: c++, c++11, size-type

code_1:

```
std::vector< std::vector<float> > grid (5, std::vector<float>(3, 1));
std::vector< std::vector <float> >::size_type rows = grid.size();
```

or

code_2:

```
std::vector< std::vector<float> > grid (5, std::vector<float>(3, 1));
std::vector<float>::size_type rows = grid.size();
```

Should I use code_1 or code_2 ? and why ?
thank you !

Comment: You should just write `auto rows = grid.size();`. Are you asking what the deduced type is for `rows`?

Comment: Of the two samples, the first is more technically correct.   Practically, however, it is likely that `std::vector<std::vector<float> >::size_type` and `std::vector<float>::size_type` are the same type.     If needed (C++11 and later) you can use `auto rows = grid.size()` or, if necessary, enforce a compile-time constraint and trigger a diagnostic if `std::vector<std::vector<float> >::size_type` and `std::vector<float>::size_type` are different types.

Comment: @Peter not merely *likely*. They are the same type by definition.

Comment: @eeronika -  The standards define no such thing.   All C++ standards from C++98 on state that a container's `size_type` is to be able to represent all positive values of a `difference_type` for that container.   With the exception of `std::array` (for which size is a template parameter of type `size_t`) there is no requirement or definition requiring that `size_type` and `std::size_t` be the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `std::vector< std::vector<float>>::size` returns value of type `std::vector< std::vector <float>>::size_type`, why would you use it to initialise a variable of type `std::vector<float>::size_type`?

That said, those are the same type, so it makes little difference. The type is `std::size_t`, so you might as well use `std::size_t rows`. Or, if you want to avoid making a mistake, let the compiler deduce the type for the variable by using `auto`.